# What is wrong with my Centos DNS server configuration?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

I need to configure an contos7 DNS server. We need to do with BIND.
To check if the server works I need to ping my DNS server on the address svr1.breda.ikdoeict.

This is the configuration of /var/named/breda.ikdoeict

```
@       IN SOA  @ breda.ikdoeict. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN      NS      @
@       IN      A       10.123.34.123
srv1    IN      A       10.129.34.123
www     IN      CNAME   srv1
```

this is the configuation of /etc/named.conf

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;10.129.34.123; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { localhost;10.129.32.0/21; };
        forwarders      { 10.129.28.230;10.129.28.232;};

        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "breda.ikdoeict" IN{
        type master;
        file "breda.ikdoeict";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key"
```

Here you can see I added the DNS to my client

```
student@student-ubuntu:~$ nmcli device show ens160 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.132.1.5
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.132.1.6
IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.129.34.123
```

when I trie to ping svr1.breda.ikdoeict it gives unknown host.

Comment: are you sure that you are using this domain name server to resolve domain names?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the resolv.conf file on the client system you are pinging from is configured with suitable `nameserver` directives and that the specified name servers are accessible from your client.